# A lot of ajax POST requests

Tags: php, ajax, architecture, nginx, memcached

I have a site with a lot of post requests (if needed I can change to GET)
for now ajax is making 1 request per second per opened tab per user.
So 20 users online = 20 requests/s + normal requests they made during visiting different pages at website. And thats assuming they all have only 1 tab.

Im looking for a better solution.
I saw nice article about microcaching in nginx, but when I tried nginx fastcgi_cache (with expiry time to 1s)- it gives me 1second hole (returns: 12:00:00, 12:00:00, 12:00:01, 12:00:01 and so on)
I can have from 10 to 80 different sets of parameters in this requests.

I was thinking about generating on the server one static file with all responses needed - but it could make file as large as 4mb, so I don't think it's a good idea.

Any ideas? Thoughts? Keywords I can search for? ;)

Comment: Does your application really need to send requests so frequently?

Comment: What are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Barmar, yes.. I was considering if I can change 1req/s to for example 5req/s, but I don't see any chance.